# Prevent foreign key errors MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

I have a array and when i try to use a INSERT on the database, i get a foreign key error. But checking which item it is, is kinda hard because the array can insert up to 15.000 items. So i created something that is really filthy:

```
foreach ($items as $index => $item) {
    try {
        // $items = ['id' => 1, 'category_id' => 2, 'product_id' => 3]

        ProductCategoryPivot::insert( $item );
    } catch( \Exception $e ) {

    }
}
```

Is there some better way to handle this? If the API returns me 15K of items, im executing 15K of queries which is a lot.

Comment: You might be interested in https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-chunk.But the real problem might be that you are inserting data into a child table which doesnt have the parent value.

Comment: Yeah thats the thing, i need those values so thats why i did a try and catch on it :S

Comment: Do  a `SELECT fk FROM child LEFT JOIN parent ON ... WHERE paretn.id IS NULL` to find the missing vals

Comment: You could query the DB first to get IDs which aren't there e.g. `Category::whereNotIn("id", array_column($items,"category_id"))` or something like that and before your insert you check if the category is there.

Comment: This error is basically saying you are trying to insert a Child row when there is no Parent row in the relationship. So you either have to check that the Parent exists before trying the insert, or check for this specific error in your Catch block and continue the loop if this is the error. Probably worth reporting the keys of the missing parent rows as well